# How to draw over everything on the screen using Qt?

Tags: qt, cross-platform

The basic idea is: I would like to draw over everything on the screen.

One way I can imagine this is creating a transparent full-screen window without window controls (minimise, maximise, etc.) or borders. Then drawing into that window which is transparent. The problem I can think of is that I will be unable to control windows which are behind our transparent window.

How could I do something similar to this, without the mentioned problem? I would also like it to work on multiple operating systems if possible.

Edit:
The user will not be drawing with the mouse or other means on the screen, but will be able to continue use his desktop like normal, without that my program interferes in any way (other than the drawing on the screen). My program will only display something on the screen, which the user will be unable to interact with (at least that's the plan).

Answer (score 2):

Qt 5 implements it:

```
QWidget w;
w.setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowTransparentForInput);
```

Qt 4 didn't support this functionality yet - see [QTBUG-13559](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-13559). The bug report had a hint on what needed to be done for Windows.

Comment: The link is broken. Where can I see the status of this issue now?

Comment: @Kolyunya It's not an issue anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The method you describe is the one to use; a transparent full-screen window.

If you're using the left mouse button to draw, you'll need a mechanism of switching modes to be able to select items through the window and send events to the operating system.

Comment: The user should (at least currently), not be able to interact with my program, my program should only display something over "the screen". My question has been updated.

Comment: Then, as I mentioned, you need to pass events through to the operating system.

Comment: Is it possible to send the events in a cross-platform way?

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe there is, you'll need to write the underlying mechanism yourself. This is quite a rare thing to do, but expect it wouldn't take a lot of code.